# How to Show/Hide buttons with Angular-UI static tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to Hide/Show different Buttons when a second tab is clicked, and the same when the default tab is clicked

[plubkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWzUzYw6h5hu8zfZ6z8T?p=preview)

```
 <tabset>
<tab heading="Home" select="showme=true"></tab>
<tab heading="Detail" select="showme=true"></tab>
 </tabset>
<div>
<input ng-hide="showme"  type="button" value="Update Home"/>
<input ng-hide="showme" type="submit" value="Save Home"/>

<input ng-show ="showme" type="button" value="Update Detail"/>
<input ng-show="showme"  type="submit" value="Save Detail" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the content of the tab inside the `<tab>` and remove the `ng-hide`/`ng-show`:

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Home" select="showme=true">

    <input type="button" value="Update Home"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Home"/>

  </tab>
  <tab heading="Detail" select="showme=true">

    <input type="button" value="Update Detail"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Detail" />

  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zp5e1iCECCBISYsoYZRU?p=preview)